# Writing layer to GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, geopackage, writers

I have a PyQGIS script which carries out a number of operations on layers and writes the results to shapefiles. However, I understand that GeoPackages have a number of advantages (not having multiple files being an obvious one) and would like to change to use them. However, I am having trouble writing to them.

Using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` I was able to write to a GeoPackage. Once. But on calling the script again I get an error:

> "a file system object (file name} already exists".

Fair enough: I added the option `QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile`. But this has no effect - I get the same error message.

If I use option `QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer` then I can overwrite an existing file, but cannot create the file in the first place: it produces an error:

> 'Opening of data source in update mode failed'.

I have tried both `writeAsVectorFormat` and `writeAsVectorFormatV2` but can get neither to work.

This is with QGIS 3.10.

Why does `CreateOrOverwriteFile` not cause the file to be overwritten? How does one code this so that it works both on the first and the subsequent times that the script is used?

```py
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
#save_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
save_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
#err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, gpkgFilePath, save_options) 
err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, gpkgFilePath, transform_context, save_options)
```

With regards to the first part of my question: it turns out to be a combination of a timing issue and an erroneous error message. Apparently, when you remove a Shape layer QGIS closes the file immediately, but when you remove a Geopackage layer it only does so later (even if it is the only layer in the file). If one then tries to overwrite the file it should produce a "file is open" message, but instead says "file already exists" (which is true but irrelevant).

As far as getting it to work is concerned, it works if I do this:

```py
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
save_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, gpkgFilePath, transform_context, save_options)

if err:
    if err[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.ErrCreateDataSource: 
        show('-- does not exist; creating file: ' + gpkgFilePath)
        save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, gpkgFilePath, transform_context, save_options)

        if err and err[0]!=0:  
            show("Error creating file with layer " + layerName + " " + str(err))
            return

    elif err[0]!=0:
        show("Error writing layer " + layerName + " " + str(err))
        return
```

Though that is awfully clunky - it's an answer, but not a terribly good one. Is there no way of doing this with a single write?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code please. Make it a runnable example so we just have to edit to specify our own file/layer to test with.

Comment: I just had an idea. A bit more experimenting suggests that the error message QGIS is giving me is itself erroneous. I will experiment further, and provide a minimal working example if I can't fix it.